# Problem with adding user to project at collection in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

I need to add new user to project in TFS 2017. In window of adding users and groups TFS not represent this user by name for project of some collection, but in another collection's project I can add this user. How can I solve this problem and get the possibility to add user to project?

Comment: How did you add the user to TFS? Is TFS in an domain environment?

Comment: Do you mean that TFS cannot identify the user when you enter the friendly name for the user?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you are in an Domain environment, the AD users will be synced to TFS first...

For the first time to add the user you need to enter the user name with domain, e. g `domain\user` or `computer\user`

> **Note**:
>
> The first time you add a user or group to Azure DevOps or TFS, you
>   can't browse to it or check the friendly name. After the identity has
>   been added, you can just type the friendly name.

Please see [Quickstart: Add users to a project or specific team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-users-team-project?view=vsts&tabs=previous-nav) for details.